# Async transaction Entity Framework 6.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, transactions

Good morning!

I have long running async transcation with fails with some different errors.

THere is method with run the transaction

```
public T PerformInTransaction<T>(Func<ITransaction> beginTransaction, Func<ITransaction, T> func)
        {
            try
            {
                AzureDbConfiguration.SuspendExecutionStrategy = true;
                using (var transaction = beginTransaction())
                {
                    return func(transaction);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                AzureDbConfiguration.SuspendExecutionStrategy = false;
            }
        }
```

The ITranscation interface is implemented as default of EF DbContextTransaction class as below:

```
public class Transaction : ITransaction
    {
        private readonly DbContextTransaction _transaction;

        public Transaction(DbContextTransaction transaction)
        {
            _transaction = transaction;
        }

        public Task CommitAsync()
        {
            this.Commit();

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

.... more methods
}
```

I have preety long operation running in transcation where inside I have loop with another async methods and each method might call SaveChanges(). Snippet basically looks like

```
await _unitOfWork.PerformInTransaction(async transaction =>
{ 
   foreach()
   {
      if(await Action())
        _unitOfWork.SaveChanges()
      else   
        transaction.Rollback()

   }

    transaction.Commit()  
})
```

The errors I have

> System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call IsDBNull
>   when reader is closed.     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CheckHeaderIsReady(Int32
>   columnIndex, Boolean permitAsync, String methodName)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.IsDBNull(Int32 i)     at
>   lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )     at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper
>   shaper)     at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.d__4.MoveNext()

or another

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider
>   failed on Commit.  ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be
>   null.  Parameter name: connection      at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String
>   parameterName)      at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbTransactionInterceptionContext.WithConnection(DbConnection
>   connection)

Do I do something wrong with async transcations? Is it related to some timouts ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: where is the context getting disposed? I suspect that the Commit is happening after the dispose of the context

Comment: context is registered in DI in rquest scope. this  fucntion is called by azure queue

Comment: How long is "pretty long running"? And does this happen every time or only sometimes?